Selecting volatility for stress scenario
I would like to stress my position in options, changing underlying price $S$ and volatility $\sigma$ at the same time.
Let's assume that after some analysis of the price history I concluded that my scenario has to be a $30\%$ decrease in the underlying's price. How do I select appropriate implied volatility changes for options in my portfolio, which go along with $-30\%$ price in the scenario?
In order of complexity, I can think of the following:

Add $+N$ bps to implied volatilities of all options in the portfolio (no justification, just do it).
Use some high historical volatility. At first, it looks better than the first approach, but implied volatility varies between strikes, so any fixed value or percentage increase might unrealistically distort the scenario across the portfolio.
Calibrate SABR and apply the backbone shift of $ATM$ to $ATM\times0.7$, recalculating the entire smile, then sample new implied volatilities from that new smile.

How do market participants source $\sigma$ changes for a given stressed shift in $S$?

Calculate the historical spot-atm vol beta and spot-skew beta at extreme events. Use these to interpolate the whole vol surface.

@volquant, could you, please, give more details about the beta approach? Should I start from the relationship of vols at relative strikes to atm vol during extreme events?

A paper by the late Marco Avellaneda http://math.stanford.edu/~papanico/pubftp/jfds.2020.1.032.full.pdf implied volatility surfaces, just like yield curves, can have historical principal components that have nice geometric interpretation, so you could have underlying move and IV PC1 and PC2 and even PC3 move 1 and 2 std's.

My recurrent nitpick - a large ul move in either direction almost, but 100% always increases iv, but we've seen e.g. canceled M&A drive both ul and iv down. You should also have scenarios - unlikely but still plausible - where ul goes down and iv also goes down. With a larger limit than the iv up scenario, because it's less likely.

Two related bits of good guidance that everyone looking at stress tests must read even when not required to follow: https://www.bis.org/bcbs/publ/d427.pdf and https://www.bis.org/bcbs/publ/d450.pdf

Not a stress testing expert, but from my own (empirical) research about how the volatility skew changes across time - you'd be surprised how insignificant the change in convexity of the volatility skew is as compared to parallel upwards shift in the volatility skew in (%) points (across time).
Therefore, I would say that (2.) is not that big of a concern.

Hmm, the change in skewness of the skew however can be material. For example if you look at sofr skew during svb, that spiked rapidly and materially.

Its not about how much the skew changed, its about how much the skew changed relative to the average level of implied vol across the skew.

@user68819 And I find it highly unlikely that the skew changes alot without a significant increase in the level of implied vol across the skew.

Oh yes, that's a given. Implied would rise dramatically
